# Function works fine on localhost but in production gives a strange error

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I have a Vue3 application and it works 100% on localhost but in production there are many problems. The one I am concerned with is the following. It's a simple Vue function to add degrees to a list and like I said it works fine on localhost.

Here is the function:

```
const education = ref([]);
const skills = ref([]);

function addDegree() {
  var list = document.getElementById("education");
  if (list.selectedIndex === 0) {
    return;
  }
  var degree = list.selectedOptions[0].innerHTML;
  if (!education.value.includes(degree)) {
    education.value.push(degree);
  } else {
    fields.value.degreeerrors.push("Degree added already");
    setTimeout(() => {
      fields.value.degreeerrors = [];
    }, 3000);
  }
  if (education.value.length >= 3) {
    const upgradeURL = "http://localhost:8080/upgrade";
    fields.value.degreeerrors.push(
      `Maximum 3 degrees. <a href="${upgradeURL}">Upgrade</a> to allow more`
    );
    setTimeout(() => {
      fields.value.degreeerrors = [];
    }, 10000);
  }
}
```

I I try and use the function on the live site I get following error in the console, which just looks completely weird and it makes no sense whatsoever:

```
TypeError: a.value is null
    Cl http://app.founderslooking.com/js/294.93f6d3fc.js:1
    i http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    s http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    n http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    _ http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    E http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    I http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    R http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    A http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    v http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    T http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    R http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    A http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    v http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    T http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    R http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    A http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    v http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    T http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    R http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    A http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    v http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    T http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    N http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    v http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    T http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    R http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    A http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    v http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    u http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    run http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    update http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    $ http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    D http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    L http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    v http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    T http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    N http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    v http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    T http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    R http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    A http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    v http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    T http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    R http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    A http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    v http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    u http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    run http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    update http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    $ http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    D http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    L http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    v http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    T http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    R http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    A http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    v http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    T http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    R http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    A http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    v http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    T http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    R http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    A http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    v http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    u http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    run http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    update http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    $ http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    D http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    L http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    v http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    u http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    run http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    update http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    $ http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    D http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    L http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    v http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    j http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    N http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    v http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    u http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    run http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    update http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    i http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    R http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    promise callback*w http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    _ http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    effect http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    j http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    I http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    Ue http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    set value http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    setup http://app.founderslooking.com/js/app.dcf5c8bb.js:1
    setTimeout handler*2549/setup/< http://app.founderslooking.com/js/app.dcf5c8bb.js:1
    we http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    i http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    s http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    __weh http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    M http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    u http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    run http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    update http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    $ http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    D http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    L http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    v http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    ee http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    mount http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    mount http://app.founderslooking.com/js/chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1
    2549 http://app.founderslooking.com/js/app.dcf5c8bb.js:1
    o http://app.founderslooking.com/js/app.dcf5c8bb.js:1
    a http://app.founderslooking.com/js/app.dcf5c8bb.js:1
    O http://app.founderslooking.com/js/app.dcf5c8bb.js:1
    <anonymous> http://app.founderslooking.com/js/app.dcf5c8bb.js:1
    <anonymous> http://app.founderslooking.com/js/app.dcf5c8bb.js:1
chunk-vendors.196cc2a7.js:1:12410
```

Comment: where is the variable `education` declared? Perhaps it's `undefined` - also, if you're using DOM methods like `document.getElementById` ... you're not using vuejs correctly

Comment: To debug, remove minimizations of all sorts from the build config, set `NODE_ENV` variable to `"production"`, compile and build the project, and run it on `localhost`, just like you would on production. Hopefully, this will give you a normal stack trace. If external resources are required (like, the server, or a database, etc.), then try bootstrapping the project in Docker or a similar tool. You can then save the new setup and use it every time you have similar errors that previously were very hard to debug.

Comment: @JaromandaX I just did not include them they are there now. Why is using document.getElementById not the right way pls?

Comment: because vuejs makes it so easy that you don't need to use them - I'm not saying it's ALWAYS wrong, but it usually is :p

Comment: Ok thank you I'll figure this out